# Is there a DMV/DMO query that will show the query plan of a SP if all code branches within it haven't executed?

Tags: sql-server

In another post ([What causes DMV to show a NULL query plan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326146/what-causes-dmv-to-show-a-null-query-plan)) I found that my DMO query returned NULL for query_plan unless all code branches within a SP had executed.  I know that SQL Server caches the statements within the SP even if all branches don't execute, but I don't know what query to use to find that plan.  Is there one?  I've copied the same code below from the other question to reproduce the issue.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SampleSp
(
@Option TINYINT
)
AS
DECLARE @RowCount INT;

-- Get ID into local temp table

CREATE TABLE #P (ID INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO #P
VALUES (1), (2)

IF @Option = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT ID FROM #P
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT ID FROM #P
END
GO

--Call SP
EXEC dbo.SampleSp 1
GO
--DMV Query to find query_plan
SELECT  
        CP.objtype, 
        CP.usecounts AS Ct, 
        ST.last_execution_time,
        SUBSTRING(Text, (statement_start_offset / 2) + 1, (CASE statement_end_offset WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(Text) ELSE statement_end_offset END  - ((statement_start_offset / 2) + 1))) AS query,
        T.text,
        PL.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS CP WITH(NOLOCK)
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(CP.plan_handle) AS T
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(CP.plan_handle) AS PL
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS ST WITH(NOLOCK) ON ST.plan_handle = CP.plan_handle
WHERE 1=1
AND ST.last_execution_time > GETDATE() - .005 -- within about the last 5 min
AND T.text LIKE '%SampleSp%'
AND T.text NOT LIKE '%dm_exec_cached_plans%'
ORDER BY ST.last_execution_time DESC
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that your explanation of the problem is accurate. Are you sure the plan isn't cached only on the second run because it was run a second time? This can happen if you have the `optimize for ad hoc workloads` setting enabled.

Comment: I'm voting to close as this seems to resolve essentially to the same problem you described in the other question - possible duplicate of [What causes DMV to show a NULL query plan?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326146/what-causes-dmv-to-show-a-null-query-plan)

Comment: I checked and optimize for ad hoc workloads is not enabled.  The question here is different from the one I referenced in that the other question asked why I got NULL for query_plan and I figured that out.  This one asks how to get a non-NULL query_plan when all branches have not executed.